# Calculate DataGrid Column values on button click

Tags: c#, datagrid

As I'm a newbie, StackOverflow doesn't let me post images. So, here is the form screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEXW7.jpg

I need code to calculate datagrid values from column "cijena" (prices) on button click. The values would be displayed in first empty text box under name "total:"

I don't know where to start, I spent several hours browsing internet but nothing helped.

Comment: Simply count the number of rows in datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

The psedo code will be like

```
 button click()
    {
      int total;
      foreach(datagridviewrow dr in datagridviewname.rows) 
      { 
         total = total + int32.Parse(dr[2].ToString())  
      } 
        textbox text = total;
    }
```

Remomber this is just pseducode....

Comment: Can you explain me this: "foreach(datagridviewrow dr"  i dont get that part, what should i do with it?

Comment: basically here you are looping across each and every row of the data grid view and for each row your are taking third column of it to convert it to integer value and saving those values.

Comment: ok so i made it to look like this:
foreach(dataGridView1 column in dataGridView1.Rows()) 
       {
           total = total + int32.Parse(column[2].ToString());

But i cant use it because of this error: .Rows cannot be used like a method in first line